# search-mailbox powershell script not working as expected

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

if i use direct powershell with exchange module, all works as expected:

```
echo $mbxs | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'received:01/07/2020..01/08/2020 AND from:test@some.com' -DeleteContent -Force
```

but if i use ps1 script, i get KQL exception:

```
$date01=(get-date).AddDays(-14).ToString("dd\/MM\/yyyy")
$date02=(get-date).AddDays(-28).ToString("dd\/MM\/yyyy")
$mails = "test@some.com","test1@some.com"
$mbxs = import-csv C:\script\names.csv
foreach ($mail in $mails) 
{
    echo $mbxs | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'received:$date02..$date01 AND from:$mail' -DeleteContent -Force
    echo $mbxs | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'sent:$date02..$date01 AND to:$mail' -DeleteContent -Force
}
Remove-Variable mbxs,mails,date01,date02
```

`The KQL parser threw an exception.`

same script worked on ps 1.0 on 2003 server, but not working on 2012 R2... what do i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple  of issues:

1. You need to use double quotes to expand the variables in the string:
2. If you are importing from a CSV you will have to reference the property.
3. You don't need to echo $mbxs down the pipe. You should be able to just state it.

It should look something like this:

```
$date01=(get-date).AddDays(-14).ToString("dd\/MM\/yyyy")
$date02=(get-date).AddDays(-28).ToString("dd\/MM\/yyyy")
$mails = "test@some.com","test1@some.com"
$mbxs = import-csv C:\script\names.csv
foreach ($mail in $mails) 
{
    $mbxs | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery "Received:$date02..$date01 AND From:$mail" -DeleteContent -Force
    $mbxs | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery "Sent:$date02..$date01 AND To:$mail" -DeleteContent -Force
}
Remove-Variable mbxs,mails,date01,date02
```

However, I'm also a little concerned because if you're importing from a  CSV you'd usually have to reference a property.  If you want to post a representative sample of the CSV data we can correct for that.

Comment: $mbxs | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery "Received:$date02..$date01 AND From:$mail" -DeleteContent -Force
 $mbxs | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery "Sent:$date02..$date01 AND To:$mail" -DeleteContent -Force

Comment: i tryed use like this, but got same error, my CSV contains Identity property.

Comment: sorry, used wrong script, all working now, thank you!